# Set Bool in custom property from view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, boolean, getter-setter, pass-data

Allocating a custom class in a vc. Then I set a bool value (either set or . notation).
The value never gets to the custom class - always reports NO.

Googled and tried many different variations - none work. What else could be wrong with the code below?

CustomView.h

```
    @interface CustomView : UIScrollView <UIScrollViewDelegate> {
    BOOL myLocalProperty;
}

@property (assign) BOOL myProperty;
```

CustomView.m

```
     @implementation CustomView

    @synthesize myProperty =_myProperty;

    - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    myLocalProperty = _myProperty;

    if (myLocalProperty==YES) {
        NSLog(@"YES");
    } else if (myLocalProperty==NO) {
        NSLog(@"NO");
    }

    return self;
}
```

ViewController.m
(in some method that is def. being called)

```
CustomView *myView = [[CustomView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

    myView.myProperty=YES;
```

This value of YES never gets to the property. Anything obviously wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of `YES` does get there, but that happens *after* you have printed the default `NO`.

The current value of `_myProperty` is printed in the initializer; by the time you assign the property `YES`, the initializer is done!

You can check that the value does get there by adding a method to show the current value of the property:

```
- (id)showMyProperty {
    myLocalProperty = _myProperty;
    if (myLocalProperty==YES) {
        NSLog(@"YES");
    } else if (myLocalProperty==NO) {
        NSLog(@"NO");
    }
}
```

Now change your code that creates `CustomView` as follows:

```
CustomView *myView = [[CustomView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
myView.myProperty=YES;
[myView showMyProperty]; // This should produce a "YES" in NSLog
```

Answer (score 1):

You're logging the value of `myProperty` in `CustomView`'s `initWithFrame:` method, but you're not assigning `YES` to `myProperty` until `initWithFrame:` has returned.  You should try logging `NSLog("myView.myProperty = %@", myView.myProperty ? @"YES" : @"NO");` *after* your assignment, `myView.myProperty = YES;`.